# Way to get all method parameters in solution

Tags: c#

Is there way in C# to get all parameters which were used with some extension method?

Example:

```
public static string GlueStrings(this string mystring, string otherString)
{
   return mystring + otherstring;
}
```

In some method in Form1

```
string string1 = "Glued";
string string2 = string1.GlueStrings("Strings");
```

In some method in Form2

```
string string1 = "Foo";
string string2 = string1.GlueStrings("bar");
```

Is there a way I can create method which would list all parameters used with that method in whole solution, I am interested in parameter `otherString` from whole solution?

UPDATE:

This with strings is just an example, I need it to work with different types. Like in MVC Controller annonations where you can get all controllers where some annonation is used.

Comment: What about strings constructed at runtime? Or do you just want the constant strings?

Comment: Full solution search using regular expressions can do this.

Comment: Is this not what "Find all references" does?

Comment: @Tyrsius I need to get it to a IEnumerable<T> somehow, not search from Visual Studio.

Comment: Why? What are you trying to achieve? What will this give you?

Comment: Oh, you want it in the code. Sorry, I misunderstood.

Answer (score 1):

You could keep a static *ConcurrentBag* in your class and add each parameter to it at runtime.

(concurrent collection for thread safety http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx)

Comment: I get you, but this would add overhead every time when this method is called.

Comment: @user1010609 just to clarify; per comment above, you're only intending to call this at startup, which means you're only interested in those parameter values that are known at compile time ... right?

Answer (score 0):

Not the best way to do it when it comes to performance

but you can use MethodBase.GetParameters

Else

how about GlueStrings(this string mystring, params object[] others)

PS: I have not tried it or unit tested it

**Update:** Example on request by you

Suppose Class Glue have the method GlueStrings then:

```
ParameterInfo[] parameterInfos = typeof (Glue).GetMethod("GlueStrings").GetParameters();
```

Comment: Can you show me example? Performance is not needed as I intend to use this code only at Application start in MVC/Webforms.

Comment: This is good, but how do I get actual values from parametarInfo, which in my example "Strings" and "bar"?

Comment: I am afraid this won't help you with your query so will delete my answer sorry for wasting your time